# ASP.NET connection to MySQL database hosted by Plesk

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server, connection-string, plesk

I have been trying to establish a connection to a database I built on Plesk, I have been having problems and am uncertain how to resolve my connectivity issue. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, and please be as detailed as possible.

[From what I have seen online it appears I might need to install some MySQL connector, but I am unaware of how to set that up on my web server]

I created the database 'mydatabase' as a MySQL database which I built using the phpmyadmin.

Once I had the table created and ready I wanted to test the connection from my ASP.NET web application to the db by simply inserting a string set to populate a single row in the database.

I copied the connection string supplied via plesk into my web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="prodTbl" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=mydatabase;Uid=admin;Pwd=password;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and then I configured the following connection code in my ASPX page;

```
Try
            Dim ProdConn As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("prodTbl").ConnectionString)



            Dim ProdCom As New SqlCommand With {.Connection = ProdConn}
            Dim ProdRdr As SqlDataReader

            ProdConn.Open()

            ProdCom.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Products (CompanyID, CompanyName, ProdName, ProdCategory, ProdStatus, ProdActiveDate, ProdIActiveDate, ProdPrice, ProdCoupons, ProdDiscount, ProdDiscountStart, ProdDiscountEnd, ProdOptions, ProdImages, Nutrition, NutServSize, NutCalories, NutCalfromFat, NutTotalFatGram, NutTotalFatPercnt, NutSatFatGram, NutSatFatPercnt, NutCholMg, NutSodMg, NutSodPercnt, NutTotCarbGram, NutTotaCarbPercnt, NutDietFibGram, NutDietFibPercnt, NutSugarGram, NutProteinGram, NutVitA, NutVitC, NutCalcium, NutIron) VALUES (@Cid, @CNme, @PNme, @Pcate, @Pstatu, @PAcDt, @IAcDt, @PPrice, @PCoupons, @PDiscnt, @PDiscntS, @PDiscntE, @POptions, @PImages, @Nutr, @ServSize, @Calories, @CalfFat, @TotalFat, @TotalFatP, @SatFat, @SatFatP, @Choles, @Sodium, @SodiumP, @TotalCarb, @TotalCarbP, @DietFiber, @Sugar, @Protein, @VitaminA, @VitaminC, @Calcium, @Iron)"
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cid", "12345")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CNme", "TestCompany")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PNme", "Pancakes")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pcate", "Breakfast")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pstatu", "Active")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAcDt", "")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IAcDt", "")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PPrice", 5.5)
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCoupons", "")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PDiscnt", 0.25)
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PDiscntS", "")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PDiscntE", "")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POptions", "Maple Syrup; Blueberries")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PImages", "BreakfastPancakes.jpg")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nutr", "Y")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServSize", "1")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Calories", "2")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CalfFat", "1")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalFat", "2")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalFatP", "1")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SatFat", "2")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SatFatP", "1")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Choles", "2")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sodium", "1")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SodiumP", "2")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalCarb", "1")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalCarbP", "2")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DietFiber", "1")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sugar", "2")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Protein", "1")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VitaminA", "2")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VitaminC", "1")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Calcium", "2")
            ProdCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Iron", "1")
            ProdCom.ExecuteNonQuery()

            ProdConn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write("<br /><br /><br /><br />FAILURE<br />" & ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Although I keep receiving the following error on my exception catch;

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'admin'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at ASP.admin_beoocatalog_aspx.dataRead(Object sender, EventArgs ea) in D:\InetPub\vhosts\becub3d.com\httpdocs\admin\BeOOCatalog.aspx:line 110 ClientConnectionId:ec0f7729-6d1b-488c-800a-d3fe4fb51055 Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:14
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding port on your connection string?  localhost:3306 (3306 is default port for mysql)

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="prodTbl" connectionString="Server=localhost:3306;Database=mydatabase;Uid=admin;Pwd=password;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Or you can try adding provider name in the web.config like below:

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="dbCon" connectionString="Server=localhost:3306;Database=mydatabase;Uid=admin;Pwd=password;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

then calling it this way:

```
Using mysqlConn As New MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbCon").ConnectionString)) 
    'Your Database Code here'
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!

I tried adding the port, and the provider name a couple of different ways. Whenever I include the port I receive a "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections."

I also saw the call for
'As New MySqlConnection'

But when I include the import in the namespace it still says it's not defined.. would I need to configure the mysql connector files on my plesk?

Comment: sorry i've  read your problem again since you've copied paste it from plesk I think if it doesn't include port number just remove it.  try resetting your mysql username password also check if it has appropriate permission to connect, read, write and etc. (not familiar with plesk but this option should have this)

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the added info. Have tried resetting the password directly, and removing the port. The user is DB admin and has all access to DB functions. From what it seems I may have to configure the mysql connector on the server first? And then mod my code to include the MySqlConnection syntax in my code...

Comment: not really familiar with plesk but last time I created web api c# with mysql it was pretty straight forward. I've just added reference to that mysql library and pretty much it, The only difference I think is I was using AWS EC2 and MYSQL RDS